# TSQL getting max and min date with a seperate but not unique record

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

example table:

```
test_date | test_result | unique_ID  
12/25/15  | 100         | 50  
12/01/15  | 150         | 75  
10/01/15  | 135         | 75   
09/22/14  | 99          | 50  
04/10/13  | 125         | 50
```

I need to find the first and last test date as well as the test result to match said date by user. So, I can group by ID, but not test result.

```
SELECT MAX(test_date)[need matching test_result],   
       MIN(test_date) [need matching test_result],   
       unique_id  
from [table]  
group by unique_id
```

THANKS!

Comment: You should include your desire output.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend window functions.  The following returns the information on 2 rows per id:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by unique_id order by test_date) as seqnum_asc,
             row_number() over (partition by unique_id order by test_date desc) as seqnum_desc
      from table t
     ) t;
```

For one row, use conditional aggregation (or `pivot` if you prefer):

```
select unique_id,
       min(test_date), max(case when seqnum_asc = 1 then test_result end),
       max(test_date), max(case when seqnum_desc = 1 then test_result end)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by unique_id order by test_date) as seqnum_asc,
             row_number() over (partition by unique_id order by test_date desc) as seqnum_desc
      from table t
     ) t
group by unique_id;
```

Comment: I guess you need `order by test_date desc` in one of your `row_number()`

Answer (score 0):

```
Create TABLE #t
    (
      test_date date ,
      Test_results int, 
      Unique_id int 
    )

INSERT  INTO #t
VALUES  ( '12/25/15',100,50 ),
        ( '12/01/15',150,75 ),
        ( '10/01/15',135,75 ),
        ( '09/22/14',99,50 ),
        ( '04/10/13',125,50 )

select 'MinTestDate' as Type, a.test_date, a.Test_results, a.Unique_id 
from #t a inner join ( 
select min(test_date) as test_datemin, max(test_date) as test_datemax, unique_id from #t 
group by unique_ID) b 
on a.test_date = b.test_datemin 

union all 

select 'MaxTestDate' as Type, a.test_date, a.Test_results, a.Unique_id from #t a 
inner join ( 
select min(test_date) as test_datemin, max(test_date) as test_datemax, unique_id from #t 
group by unique_ID) b 
on a.test_date = b.test_datemax
```

Comment: Sorry I'm new to this, my formatting is crap and I'm not sure how to link sql query so nicely like you guys have..but I hope you can copy paste this over, and it will look better..

Comment: select the text and use `ctrl-K` or add 4 space before each line

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a combination of self-joins and derived tables:

```
SELECT t1.unique_id, minTable.MinOftest_date, t1.test_result As Mintestdate_result, 
       maxTable.MaxOftest_date, t2.test_result As Maxtestdate_result

FROM TestTable AS t1 
INNER JOIN 
           (
            SELECT Min(TestTable.test_date) AS MinOftest_date,
                   TestTable.unique_ID
            FROM TestTable
            GROUP BY TestTable.unique_ID
           ) As minTable 
    ON (t1.test_date = minTable.MinOftest_date 
    AND t1.unique_id = minTable.unique_id)

INNER JOIN TestTable As t2     
INNER JOIN 
           (
            SELECT Max(TestTable.test_date) AS MaxOftest_date, 
                   TestTable.unique_ID
            FROM TestTable
            GROUP BY TestTable.unique_ID
           )  AS maxTable 
    ON t2.test_date = maxTable.MaxOftest_date
    AND t2.unique_ID = maxTable.unique_ID

ON minTable.unique_id = maxTable.unique_id;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
unique_id   MinOftest_date  Mintestdate_result  MaxOftest_date  Maxtestdate_result
50               4/10/2013                 125      12/25/2015                 100
75               10/1/2015                 135       12/1/2015                 150
```